# Client side recognition of connection loss between opc ua server and plc in milo

Tags: java, opc-ua, milo

I am using a Siemens S7 plc and an external opc ua server device (IBH Link UA).
On the client side I created a java application using milo to exchange data between the server and my client system. 
Is there any way to recognize on the client side if the server loses the connection to the plc (e.g. somebody turns off the S7)? 
Maybe some Listener or something?

When using UAExpert to display the data it reacts with empty value fields and a "BadNoCommunication" Statuscode to me turning off the S7. So I guess there is some way to do this.

I tried to add a NotificationListener implementing the onStatusChangedNotification to the subscription.
But it doesn't get invoked in this situation.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `SessionActivityListener` via `OpcUaClient::addSessionActivityListener`.

`onSessionInactive` will be called if the session becomes inactive.

You do not need to take any action in this case, the client attempts to reconnect and re-establish a Session automatically. You'll be notified when a Session is activated via `onSessionActive`.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your help! I am not planing to do anything opc-wise. I just need a way to inform the systems behind the opc ua client that there is currently no reliable data. I will try the SessionActivityListener and get back to you with the results.

Comment: I added a SessionActivityListener to my OpcUaClient-object but onSessionActive /-Inactive are not being called when I turn the S7 off or on. It seems it is only called when I switch the opc ua server device off or on. Do you maybe have another suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question. If you are connected to an OPC UA server, and that server is in turn connected to a PLC, then if the connection between server and PLC is lost it is the server's responsibility to report that to the client somehow, usually via setting Bad or Uncertain StatusCodes on MonitoredItems or in response to reads. You will not get notified via the SessionActivityListener.